# Dihedral group of order 8

Tags: group-theory

Writing Dihedral group $D_{8}$ (order 8)as a semidirect product $%
V\left\langle \alpha \right\rangle $, where $V$ is a four-group and $\alpha $
an involution, and so we have $D_{8}=\left\langle \alpha ,\beta \right\rangle $ and
$V=\left\langle \beta ,\beta ^{\alpha }\right\rangle .$

I want to show that: Let $D$ be isomorphic with $D_{8}=\left\langle \alpha
,\beta \right\rangle $ and suppose that $D$ acts on a group $G$ in such a
manner that $C_{G}(V)$ is finte, where $V=\left\langle \beta ,\beta ^{\alpha
}\right\rangle $ and $\alpha $ sends every element of $G$ to the inverse,
then $C_{G}\left( \beta \right) $ is finite.

My solution:

Let $\phi \in AutG,$ then $g^{\phi \alpha }=\left( g^{-1}\right) ^{\phi }$
and $g^{\alpha \phi }=\left( g^{-1}\right) ^{\phi }$. Therefore $\alpha \in
Z\left( AutG\right) $ and so $C_{G}(\left\langle \beta ,\beta ^{\alpha
}\right\rangle )=C_{G}\left( \beta \right) $ is finite. ($V=\left\langle
\beta \right\rangle$???)

I think there's a problem in my solution for the Klein group is not cyclic.

Help!

Comment: Your solution looks basically OK to me. Since the action of $\alpha$ is central in ${\rm Aut} G$, the actions of $\beta$ and $\beta^\alpha$ on $G$ are the same, so $C_G(\beta) = C_G(\beta^\alpha) = C_G(V)$. Why should this imply that $V = \langle \beta \rangle$?

Comment: Because $V=\left\langle \beta ,\beta ^{\alpha }\right\rangle $ and $\beta
^{\alpha }=\beta .$ Would not it be so?

Comment: It is not true that $\beta^\alpha = \beta$. They induce the same automorphism of $G$, but that does not make them equal. It implies that $\beta^{-1}\beta^\alpha$ induces the identity automorphism of $G$, which means that the action of $D_8$ on $G$ is not faithful.

Comment: Lima:I understood. Thank you!